# Capturing repeated pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to implement some kind of markdown like behavior for a Python log formatter.

Let's take this string as example:

`**This is a warning**: Virus manager __failed__`

A few regexes later the string has lost the markdown like syntax and been turned into bash code:

`\033[33m\033[1mThis is a warning\033[0m: Virus manager \033[4mfailed\033[0m\033[0m`

But that should be compressed to

`\033[33;1mThis is a warning\033[0m: Virus manager \033[4mfailed\033[0m`

I tried these, beside many other non working solutions:

`(\\033\[([\d]+)m){2,}` => Capture: `\033[33m\033[1m` with g1 '\033[1m' and g2 '1' and `\033[0m\033[0m`with g1 '\033[0m' and g2 '0'

`(\\033\[([\d]+)m)+` many results, not ok

`(?:(\\033\[([\d]+)m)+)` many results, although this is the recommended way for repeated patterns if I understood correctly, not ok

and others..

My goal is to have as results:

Input
`\033[33m\033[1mThis is a warning\033[0m: Virus manager \033[4mfailed\033[0m\033[0m`

Output

**Match 1**
`033[33m\033[1m`

*Group1*: 33

*Group2*: 1

**Match 2**
`033[0m\033[0m`

*Group1*: 0

*Group2*: 0

In other words, capture the ones that are "duplicated" and not the ones alone, so I can fuse them with a regex sub.

Comment: there is a lot of unnecessary information, can you post a sample input and the expected output?

Comment: It's at the end... input: \033[33;1mThis is a warning\033[0m: Virus manager \033[4mfailed\033[0m output read the end of the message

Comment: The number of match groups created by an expression will always be a set value. For instance `(...)+` will generate only one match group.

Comment: This is not 100% clear: what are the rules? Can you have `\033[33m\033[1m\033[22m`? If yes, what is the expected output?

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'(?:\\033\[\d+m){2,}', lambda m: r'\033['+";".join(set(re.findall(r"\[(\d+)", m.group())))+'m', text)`

Answer (score 1):

The patterns in the string to be modified have not been made clear from the question. For example, is `033` fixed or might it be `025` or even `25`? I've made certain assumptions in using the regex

```
r" ^(\\0(\d+)\[\2)[a-z]\\0\2\[(\d[a-z].+)
```

to obtain two capture groups that are to be combined, separated by a semi-colon. I've attempted to make clear my assumptions below, in part to help the OP modify this regex to satisfy alternative requirements.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/guDRo7/3/)

The regex performs the following operations:

```
^           # match beginning of line
(           # begin cap grp 1
  \\0       # match '\0'
  (\d+)     # match 1+ digits in cap grp 2
  \[        # match '['
  \2        # match contents of cap grp 2
)           # end cap grp 1
[a-z]       # match a lc letter
\\0         # match '\0'      
\2          # match contents of cap grp 2
\[          # match '['
(\d[a-z].+) # match a digit, then lc letter then 1+ chars to the
            #   end of the line in cap grp 3
```

As you see, the portion of the string captured in group 1 is

```
\033[33
```

I've assumed that the part of this string that is now `033` must be two or more digits beginning with a zero, and the second appearance of a string of digits consists of the same digits after the zero. This is done by capturing the digits following '0' (`33`) in capture group 2 and then using a back-reference `\2`.

The next part of the string is to be replaced and therefore is not captured:

```
m\\033[
```

I've assumed that `m` must be one lower case letter (or should it be a literal `m`?), the backslash and zero and required and the following digits must again match the content of capture group 2.

The remainder of the string,

```
1mThis is a warning\033[0m: Virus manager \033[4mfailed\033[0m\033[0m
```

is captured in capture group 3. Here I've assumed it begins with one digit (perhaps it should be `\d+`) followed by one lower case letter that needn't be the same as the lower case letter matched earlier (though that could be enforced with another capture group). At that point I match the remainder of the line with `.+`, having given up matching patterns in that part of the string.

One may alternatively have just two capture groups, the capture group that is now #2, becoming #1, and #2 being the part of the string that is to be replaced with a semicolon.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I will test and return my results asap!

Answer (score 1):

You want to match consectuively repeating `\033[\d+m` chunks of text and join the numbers after `[` with a semi-colon.

You may use

```
re.sub(r'(?:\\033\[\d+m){2,}', lambda m: r'\033['+";".join(set(re.findall(r"\[(\d+)", m.group())))+'m', text)
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/4yIoYV)

The `(?:\\033\[\d+m){2,}` pattern will match two or more sequences of `\033[` + one or more digits + `m` chunks of texts and then, the match will be passed to the lambda expression, where the output will be: 1) `\033[`, 2) all the numbers after `[` extracted with `re.findall(r"\[(\d+)", m.group())` and deduplicated with the `set`, and then 3) `m`.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward for the cases you desribe here; simply write out from left to right what you want to match and capture. Repeating capturing blocks won't help you here, because only the most recently captured values would be returned as a result.

```
\\033\[(\d+)m\\033\[(\d+)m
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is only valid for 2 consecutive, not random N consecutives

Comment: Sure. My point was, that you're not doing this with one expression and repeating capturing groups. You'd typically use one expression to grab the sequence as a whole, a second (or string functions) to grab a list of numbers from it and some logic to process the values -- as in Wiktor Stribiżew's answer.